# Specifying coordinate reference system (CRS) for scalebar that is different to project CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, units, grids-graticules, scale-bar

Is it possible to specify a coordinate reference system (CRS) for the scalebar that is different to the project CRS?

For example, my project CRS uses geographic coordinates (lat/long), the reason being that I need a lat/long graticule on the map. However I would like the scalebar to be expressed in kilometres (i.e. projected distance units, rather than angular measures).

An alternative solution would be for QGIS to have the capability to specify the CRS of the map grid / graticule, as in ArcMap.

This is not simply a question about how to select scalebar units (e.g. miles / kilometres / metres).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement the alternative solution you can try this tutorial on **[Two Different Graticules with QGIS](http://www.surfaces.co.il/?p=616)** to implement a different CRS graticule.

Comment: Andre - many thanks. Indeed this is the temporary fix that we're planning to use. It works well, although the drawbacks are (a) it's time consuming for each new area to be mapped, and (b) grid labels for the 'false' grid (the one based on a vector grid layer) must be internal to the map frame rather than arranged outside of the neatline.